# Search and replace text with IMACROS

Tags: search, text, replace, imacros

I just made this macro

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:product-form ATTR=ID:Name EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:IT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:product-form ATTR=ID:Locales_0__Name CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

After this, I would like to check all the text inside {{VAR1}}, in order to correct part of grammal errors like "é" instead of "è" and something like this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the EVAL command for this purpose. For example:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/é/g, \"è\");")
```

http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate that.
By the way with this command I can replace only one letter and only on pasted text.
Is there a way to operate on the source text too?

Comment: And how can I replace more than one word inside this var?
Thank you in advantage :)

Comment: You can string together multiple calls of the replace function. For example, the following would replace all instances of the word 'this' with 'that' and all instances of 'you' with 'me':

`SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/this/g, \"that").replace(/you/g, \"me\");")`

You can't change the HTML source code with this command.